# remove strikethrough from highchart legend symbol

Tags: highcharts

How could I remove the strike through from legend symbol when its in disabled mode. I just want symbol to be greyed out.

[Please click to see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2zev.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can set `drawLegendSymbol` from column series as the default one:

```
(function(H) {
    H.Series.prototype.drawLegendSymbol = H.seriesTypes.column.prototype.drawLegendSymbol;
})(Highcharts);
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/oyzLe26a/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts